# Create 2d triangles from 2d points

Tags: algorithm, graphics

I have to make 2d triangles from a list of 2d points with a condition: length of any edge can't be longer than a predefined constant.

Something like this:
[image]

Do you know any algorithm that can do this? Or any advise?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try [Delaunay triangulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delaunay_triangulation), then remove any edges which are too long.

From the above article, you see a link to [CGAL's 2D triangulation page](http://www.cgal.org/Manual/latest/doc_html/cgal_manual/packages.html#Part:TriangulationsAndDelaunayTriangulations).

Comment: +1 for Delaunay triangulation. This inherently forms well "balanced" triangles. This should do a reasonable job of minimizing the chances of overlong edges, but it doesn't make any guarantees about specific edge lengths. I don't think you can just remove overlong edges, but if there's a problem, it seems unlikely (though not impossible?) that there's an alternative triangulation that works. Trouble is, even if it's possible (not sure - my computation geometry is rusty) it will probably be hard to find. It may be a try-all-possible-triangulations kind of thing.

Answer (score 3):

First, generate all possible edges (i.e. connecting a pair of vertices that are closer than the constant). Then when two of them intersect, remove one of them. Repeat this step until there are no intersections.

This solution is quite primitive, it's probably possible to do it faster.

Answer (score 2):

I like svick's answer -

when implementing I would do the following

1. calculate the lines between every pair of points
2. Sort the list by length
3. Remove all lines longer than your threshold
4. Continue down the list (longest to shortest) if it crosses another line then remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Coming a bit late to the party, but I had a similar problem (triangulation of a set of points in two dimensions with boundary constraints)...

Unfortunately, svick's algorithm combined with pondulus' suggestion has the following flaw. Consider a complete graph with five vertices as seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xhf9h.png). By removing edges (longest to shortest) that intersect with other edges outside of their endpoints, one arrives at the last graph of the picture. Clearly, the resulting set of edges cannot give rise to a triangulation. To formalise the notion of a triangulation, we are looking for a "maximal set of non-crossing edges between points" as written in the wikipedia article on [point-set triangulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point-set_triangulation).

There is an easy fix for this problem: After running svick's & pondulus' algorithm, we arrive at a set of edges which surely only consists of non-crossing edges, but must not be maximal (as seen in the example). To make this set a triangulation, we can iterate all remaining possible edges again and add those that do not intersect with existing ones.

Although the runtime is not great (my implementation behaves like O(n^3) for n the number of points; see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/88UQ9.png) for the heuristic), I appreciate the flexibility of including any kind of constraint on the set of allowed edges, e.g. maximum length like in Mart's problem or boundary constraints as in my case.